# react-materialize input não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery, react, materialize

Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, criei um site usando apenas o materialize e depois usei a biblioteca do React no template, porém agora alguns campos não estão funcionando e um deles é o input eu tive que remover o jquery em algumas partes pois vi em alguns fóruns que não é recomendado usar o jquery junto ao react. Segue abaixo o código do input e uma imagem mostrando o ocorrido quando tento digitar algo no input.

```
render() {
    const { open } = this.state;

    return (
        <Modal open={open} onClose={this.handleCloseModal} center styles={this.state.styles}>
            <form method="" action="">
                <div className="row">
                    <h5>Solicitar ligação</h5>
                </div>
                <div className="row">

                    <div className="input-field col s12 m12 l6 ">
                        <input onChange={this.handleChangeInput} value={this.state.form.name} name='name' type="text"/>
                        <label>Nome / Sobrenome</label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="input-field col col s12 m12 l6">
                        <input onChange={this.handleChangeInput} value={this.state.form.phone} name="phone" type="text"/>
                        <label>Telefone</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div className="modal-footer">
                <button onClick={this.handleSubmitForm} style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.theme.primary }} href="#" className="btn waves-effect btn modal-action" type="submit" name="action">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

E a imagem demonstrando o ocorrido, note que ao digitar o meu nome o label não sobe.

[image: input-materialize]

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou tão clara, está utilizando o materialize com jQuery ou o react-materialize?

Comment: Na verdade eu comecei o projeto em materialize e depois migrei para o react, caso não esteja clara ainda minha questão, me informe que irei edita-la.

Comment: Sim, está utilizando o react, mas com qual materialize? O que utiliza jQuery puro e que não é indicado usar com frameworks js ou este react-materialize?

Comment: Experimente trocar o label de lugar com a input. label primeiro, input depois.